# SSH disconnects after ~10 mins and can't reconnect

Tags: ssh

After around 10 minutes of starting up my Raspberry Pi (Model 4b) and being SSH'd into it, it freezes. If I try to reconnect I just get connection timed out.

I've connected it to a monitor and it still works fine.

I can also ping it fine from the PC I'm trying to connect from

```
C:\Users\jandr>ping 192.168.1.105

Pinging 192.168.1.105 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.105: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.105: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.105: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.105: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.105:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 3ms
```

I've tried turning WiFi power management off but that didn't help either and I don't think that's the issue because the WiFi still works fine when I can't SSH in.

I can also still connect using VNC.

`sudo service ssh status` shows it as running and even if I try `sudo service ssh restart` and try again it still won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options from `man sshd_config` that might help:

> **ClientAliveCountMax**
>
> Sets the number of client alive messages which may be sent without sshd(8) receiving any messages back from the client.  If
> this threshold is
> reached while client alive messages are being sent, sshd will disconnect the client, terminating the session.  It is important
> to note that the
> use of client alive messages is very different from TCPKeepAlive.  The client alive messages are sent through the
> encrypted channel and there‐
> fore will not be spoofable.  The TCP keepalive option enabled by TCPKeepAlive is spoofable.  The client alive mechanism is
> valuable when the
> client or server depend on knowing when a connection has become unresponsive.
>
> The default value is 3.  If ClientAliveInterval is set to 15, and ClientAliveCountMax is left at the default, unresponsive SSH
> clients will be
> disconnected after approximately 45 seconds.  Setting a zero ClientAliveCountMax disables connection termination.
>
> **ClientAliveInterval**
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through
> the encrypted
> channel to request a response from the client.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the
> client.

Notice that although the default for the first one is three, the default for the last is 0 so the feature is not used. My preferred settings are:

```
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 15
```

Although ostensibly this about not keeping clients logged in when they are non-responsive, this and `TCPKeepAlive` (enabled by default) should help prevent that from happening as there will always be a certain amount of actual data passed back and forth.

Comment: I changed those two settings, rebooted my Raspberry PI and SSH'd in. After 10 minutes again the session was unresponsive, I tried to reconnect and it timed out. The Raspberry Pi still working fine over VNC though.